# How to format date in HTML for blind

Tags: html, macos, voiceover

I am trying to make my blog as much as possible accessible and besides other things i can't figure out how to make dates of posts red as date by OS X VoiceOver. It always read numbers and dots. For example 24.02.2012 it reads like 2,4,dot,zero,2,dot,.....  I know date formats differ around the world, but at least some starting point would be nice ;)

I was trying both system in english and czech, also english and czech voice and all it's combinations.

Comment: Try using the `<time>` element's `datetime` attribute: `<time datetime="2012-02-24">24.02.2012</time>`

Comment: Testing on Yosemite 10.10.2, @Blender's suggestion sadly does not work. Seems there is no way to infer a date in the browser from what I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expect all voice overs to read it the same way. Your safest bet is to spell it out instead.